# Python text file cleaning, two numbers in a row with no obvious seperation

Tags: python, data-cleaning

I am working on some code to clean a data file for further processing afterwards.

I am missing a way of seperating values that have no obvious seperation. However I know that the values should be seperated using the following rule:

- seperate/add a space, when there is a negative sign except when the previous letter was an E

I have a very watered down example of the type of text I would use this on:

```
CSYS,   0
NBLOCK,6,SOLID,        15,        15
(3i9,6e21.13e3)
        1        0        0 4.0000000000000E+001-6.0000000000000E+001
        2        0        0 4.0000000000000E+001 6.0000000000000E+001
        3        0        0-4.0000000000000E+001 6.0000000000000E+001
```

Expected output for the nblock dictionary:

```
nblock = [[6.0, 'SOLID', 15.0, 15.0],
          ['(3i9,6e21.13e3)'],
         [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40.0, -60.0],
         [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 60.0],
         [3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -40.0, 60.0]]]
```

I can get that output if I add a space manually between 0-4 and 1-6 but I need a way of doing this automatically.

Here is the current code I use to get the (almost) correct output:

```
class Block:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}
        self.array = []

    def ingest(self, lines):
        for line in lines:
            
            # if string starts with a new line we skip
            if line[0] == '\n':
                continue
            
            # if string starts with a letter
            elif 'a' <= line[0] <= 'z' or 'A' <= line[0] <= 'Z':
                parts = [k.strip() for k in line.split(',')] 
                parts = [float(k) if k.isdigit() else k for k in parts]
                key = parts[0].lower()
                if key not in self.data:
                    self.data[key] = [parts[1:]]
                else:
                    self.data[key].append( parts[1:] )
            
            # if string first letter is any of the following we skip iterating 
            elif line[0] == '\t' or line[0] == '/' or line[0] == '*' or line[0] == '_' or line[0] == '!':
                continue

            elif line[0] == '(':
                self.data[key].append( [line.strip()] )
                self.data[key].append( [] )
            else:
                parts = line.split()
                if parts[0] != '-1':
                    self.data[key][-1].append( [float(k) for k in parts[:]] )


blk = Block() 
blk.ingest( open(input_file) ) 
my_data = blk.data
```

Comment: it looks like the data is in fixed length columns... is that correct?

Comment: @livelysteak where does the `CSYS` go?, do you just lose it during the formatting of the file?

Comment: @thebjorn the rows are of fixed length not the columns.

Comment: @Fahim CSYS will go into a different dictionary, a long with a lot of other stuff. Only the nblock dictionary is causing this issue for me.

Comment: @livelysteak okay okay, gotcha buddy!

Answer (score 0):

you should totaly look into [regular expresions](https://regexr.com/) with the "re" (regex) module

example of code for you:

```
import re
rex = r"(?: *(-?\d) *(-?\d) *(-?\d) *(-?\d*\.?\d+(?:E\+\d+)) *(-?\d*\.?\d+(?:E\+\d+)))"
txt = """
        1        0        0 4.0000000000000E+001-6.0000000000000E+001
        2        0        0 4.0000000000000E+001 6.0000000000000E+001
        3        0        0-4.0000000000000E+001 6.0000000000000E+001
"""
tab = re.findall(rex,txt)
print(tab)
```

will print

```
[('1', '0', '0', '4.0000000000000E+001', '-6.0000000000000E+001'),
('2', '0', '0', '4.0000000000000E+001', '6.0000000000000E+001'),
('3', '0', '0', '-4.0000000000000E+001', '6.0000000000000E+001')]
```

Comment: Hmm the regex syntax is like complete gibberish to me but I will look into it. I tried running it on my data and there is an issue where your code will skip some lines. See https://i.imgur.com/gxitDmB.png

Comment: @livelysteak there i fixed it `(?: *(-?\d+) *(-?\d+) *(-?\d+) *(-?\d*\.?\d+(?:E.\d+)) *(-?\d*\.?\d+(?:E.\d+)))` i forgot to take the '-' in count in 'E-001' syntax, regex is very powerfull, i really recommand to learn it for any data parsing

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a way to do it with built-in functions

Hopefully, this works:

## Code

```
def format_data(txt):
  o = []
  lw = []
  s_row = []
  
  arr = []
  output = []
  for i in open(txt,"r").read().splitlines():
    if "  " in i[0:3]:
      line_frmt = i[8:].split("        ")
      s_row.append(line_frmt[2].replace("-","")[0])
      lw.append(line_frmt)
      x = line_frmt[2].split(" ")
      if len(x)>2:
        o.append(x[1:])
      else:
        j = [d.split("-") for d in x]
        for i in j:
          if len(i)>=2:
            i[1] = "-"+i[1]
            o.append(i)
    
    elif "(" in i:
      output.append([i])
      
    elif "  " in i[15:19]:
      header = i.replace("  ","").split(",")[1:]
      az = []
      for j in header:
        if j[0] in list("1234567890-"):
          az.append(float(j))
        else:
          az.append(str(j))
      output.append(az)
  
  for v in range(len(lw)):
    data = lw[v][:2]+o[v]
    if len(data)>len(set(data)):
      del data[2]
      data = data+[lw[v][2].split(" ")[1]]
    
    arr.append([float(x) for x in lw[v][:2]+[s_row[v]]+data[2:]])
  output.append(arr)
  
  
  return output


nblock = format_data("f.txt") #change it to the filename
print(nblock)
```

## Output

```
[[6.0, 'SOLID', 15.0, 15.0], 
 ['(3i9,6e21.13e3)'], 
 [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40.0, -60.0], 
 [2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 60.0], 
 [3.0, 0.0, 0.0, -40.0, 60.0]]]
```

- Sorry if there are a few memory leaks

Comment: On the line with `data = data+[lw[v][2].split(" ")[1]]` I get a list index out of range error. I can only make your code work when I add the spaces manually beforehand.

Comment: My code will work if the data in the file is the same as the data on the example sample